# CD/ DVD Silverlight SQLite App

Tags: silverlight, sqlite, autorun

Does anyone have experience in developing a standalone app with Silverlight using SQLite database? App should be distributed on CD or DVD for Windows OS and has to have autorun, with possibility to install .NET Framework if needed.
How difficult is to develop that kind of app for someone who has two years experience in Asp.NET web forms apps?
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Please double-check what your goals are:

- SQLite does not run on Silverlight, or at least there aren't widely used ports of it available in any form
- Silverlight can't install .NET Framework, and in fact does not even require it